# Consume taxonomy collection from Sharepoint 2013 Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-object-model

I'm able to successfully get back a list of Genres I have stored in Sharepoint. It's unofficially a `TaxonomyCollection` I believe. The way the client object sends it back is kind of strange and difficult to take and put into another form. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Here's the JSON I get back: (See items under Genres node). I want to get the `Label` value for example. Looks pretty straight forward.

[image]

Now this is what actually comes back in the client object model.

[image]

This is just crazy, here's the code I wrote just to get the label for one genre:

```
var items = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contacts").GetItems(itemsQuery);
//Execution code removed for brevity
Dictionary<string,object> g = ((Dictionary<string,object>)items.ToList()
                               .First()["Genres"]);
var g2 = g.ToList()[1];
var g3 = (object[])g2.Value;
var g4 = (object[])((Dictionary<string, object>) g3[0]).Values.ToArray();
var g5 = g4[1].ToString();
```

As you can see it's ugly and writing a linq statement to ultimately get all the labels is equally as ugly and difficult to write. I am thinking that I am doing it wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using [this as a reference.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14891/how-do-i-get-the-terms-used-in-a-taxonomyfield)

The solution was:

```
(items[0]["Genres"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection).ToList().Select(x=> x.Label);
```